# Assigning C-function pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

### **Edited**

I want to bind C function pointer of `class X` to another member function of `class Y`.

Their implementation looks like this

```
//The class w/c has the C-function pointer
class XString
{
public:
    ...
private:
    void (*eventOnChange)();

    friend class swc::swcText;
};
```

---

```
//The class w/c I want to assign/bind the XString::eventOnChange;
class swcText
{
public:

    swcText()
    {
        //how can I do this
        text.eventOnChange = &swcText::computeTextSize;
    }
    ...

    XString text;
private:

    void computeTextSize();
};
```

I want to achieve the `text.evenOnChange = this->computeTextSize` but I got a compilation

```
error ..\swctext.cpp|25|error: cannot convert 'void (swc::swcText::*)()' to 'void (*)()' in assignment|
```

I know I can do this using a `std::function<void()> eventOnChange` and assign a lambda function, but how to do this in a C-style function pointer?

Comment: `std::bind` doesn't do what you think... It doesn't bind a function to another function in the sense of assignment, but it returns a **new** function which mimics the first argument (original function) with some fixed arguments but maybe some "missing" arguments (something like a partial fixing of arguments); it doesn't modify anything.

Comment: I would suggest reading the doc's for std::bind to see whether it returns a success/failure value (I suspect it does).  Also, swcText::computeTextSize is not a function-taking-no-arguments-returning-void, since it takes an argument (the implicit this).  Perhaps you want a free function taking a swcText argument?

Comment: @pepper_chico I'm sorry if this post appears troll for you but I don't get what do you mean by that.

Comment: @mr5 nevermind, it just looked like a play of words regarding `bind` and "binding functions" as with C# delegates. `std::bind` bind arguments, just that.

Comment: @mr5 dispite that, if you care, the C++ POCO library provides delegates a la C#. You may also look at boost signals 2.

Comment: @leemes But how can I assign the `function pointer` to another function w/c is a member of another class? I have really a bad understanding about `bindings` of function, I thought it does what I think.

Comment: It seems you are looking for [`boost::signal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals.html), not `boost::bind`.

Comment: @pepper_chico I have wrong thoughts about `bind`, I thought it somewhat resolve compilation error for assigning function pointer. I have edited my question, mind look at this again?

Comment: @mr5 ok I see it. What I advice is that, learn something about member function pointers, and then, just don't use them because they're hard to get right. keep with `std::function` et al

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for mentioning that. But I need to profile first what will be best suited to my needs.

Answer (score 3):

When you call a non-`static` member function you always pass a reference to an object into the function, i.e., the entity which is pointed to by `this`. A function declared as `void(*)()` doesn't take any parameter and is, thus, incompatible with a member function pointer: there is no way to assign them. You need to get hold of the additional object somehow. The easiest approach is, of course, to just use a `std::function<void()>` and `std::bind()` your function to the object (there is no need to use lambdas):

```
std:function<void()> f;
f = std::bind(&Y::computeTextSize, this);
```

If you insist that you don't want to use anything like that you could build functions similar to `std::function<void()>` and `std::bind()` which are extremely limited:

```
class function
{
    void* object;
    void (*fun)(void*);
public:
    function(): object(), fun() {}
    function(void* o, void(*f)(void*)): object(o), fun(f) {}
    void operator()() const { if (object) (this->fun)(object); }
};

template <typename T, void (T::*member)()>
void call(void* object) {
    (static_cast<T*>(object)->*member)();
}
template <typename T, void (T::*member)()>
function bind(T* object) {
    return function(object, &call<T, member>);
}
```

You'd use the above functions like

```
text.eventOnChange = bind<swcText, &swcText::computeTextSize>(this);
```

Note, however, that `std::function<...>` and `std::bind()` tend to pull off quite a few extra tricks and can be used more efficiently, especially when passing function objects with inline call operators to them (in addition to being *a lot* more flexible).